# How to use onmouseover on table cell to change a string into a pre-filled textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

All,

I'm generated a dynamic table of first and last names.  I would like to integrate a `onmouseover` function that would make the text editable, and one `onmouseout` that will make the text "hard" again.

My question is how to structure the table cell in cases where the text is "hard" and when it's editable?  Is it a good idea to include the text inside `<p>` tags within the `<td>` when the text is "hard".  Is the right way to make it editable to replace the `<p>` with `<textarea>`? Where should I place the functions? As I have it right now, the browser registers several `onmouseover` events when I bring the pointer in a single time - why is that?

The PHP code that creates the table's `<tbody>` looks like this:

```
<?php
 $i=0;
 foreach ($nameArray as $name){
   echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td  id='first_".$i."' onmouseover='editOn(this)' onmouseout='editOff(this)'>
       <p>".$name[0]."</p>
     </td>";
     echo "<td  id='last_".$i."' onmouseover='editOn(this)' onmouseout='editOff(this)'>
       <p>".$name[0]."</p>
     </td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   $i++;
 }
?>
```

Comment: No, the PHP script that *generates* the `tbody` looks like that. The `tbody` *itself* will look like some HTML between `<tbody>` and `</tbody>` tags. Could you post that, please? JavaScript questions rely upon the generated HTML as seen by the browser, the server-side script is irrelevant.

Comment: There is no "onmouseoff" attribute, I think you want onmouseout.

Comment: I corrected those two.

Comment: I've recently coded a piece that similar in an open-source project, using JS. http://github.com/alfredxing/wylst